no funciona la conexion en mi app node.js con mysql
estoy usando un hosting de hostinger para alojar mi base de datos mysql y un VPS para alojar mi app web pero no deja comunicar correctament, me tira este error...
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}

Node.js v20.13.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

cambie varias veces las credenciales de la base de datos mysql pero no estoy seguro que me hace falta, si alguien sabe por favor ayudame
